# Can not change Mysql Server 8 root password Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: kubuntu, mysql

I have a fresh installation of **Kubuntu 19.10** and **Mysql Server 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1**

I tried to start mysql with command below:

```
sudo mysqld --init-file=/home/da/dainit &
```

I've an init file under **/home/da/dainit** contains and tried varied of choices like

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'abc';
```

or

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('p@ssw0rd')
WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

(Although I knew that it does not work for mysql 8.x)

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root-password';
```

Nothing worked.

Init file has an error message like this:

```
2020-01-21T06:48:13.933707Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) starting as process 8530
2020-01-21T06:48:14.430914Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-01-21T06:48:14.455683Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-000029 - File '/home/da/dainit' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2020-01-21T06:48:14.455730Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010455] [Server] Failed to open the bootstrap file /home/da/dainit
2020-01-21T06:48:14.455742Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-01-21T06:48:15.513739Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

I've applied the command

```
sudo chown mysql:adm /home/da/dainit
```

than got errors:

```
2020-01-21T09:59:17.896016Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) starting as process 5731
2020-01-21T09:59:18.441042Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-01-21T09:59:18.443337Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010273] [Server] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.
2020-01-21T09:59:18.443715Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010268] [Server] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
2020-01-21T09:59:18.444373Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-01-21T09:59:19.473693Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

Answer (score 1):

> File '/home/da/dainit' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied

That should be pretty easy: that file is not owned by your mysql user. Mysql has its own user and requires files you want to access to be owned by that user.

```
sudo chown mysql:adm /home/da/dainit
```

would fix it.  (mysql:adm are defaults; if you changed those change to what you need)

Comment: I ve already changed it to 777. And then I got innodb file lock.

Comment: We take security serious. Please follow the correct procedures when using mysql (or any other service in linux). chmod 777 is -never- the correct answer.

Comment: Just tried to see what happens. Just for seeing the gd mysql working : )

Comment: Tried and got latest paragraph @rinzwind